# Where i get the life cycle between UIView, UINaviagtionController and UIViewController?

Tags: iphone

I am a beginner in IPhone Development. I very confused on the behaviour or life cycle between UIView, UINavigationController and UIViewController.
Please suggest me any documentation on it which has to be fully understandable diagrammatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple's View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)